# Using TFLite model on Xtensa for acceleration of ML algorithms

Tags: c++, tensorflow-lite, xtensa

I was working on CNN acceleration on XTensa by using TFLite models.I used the convolution model of TFlite and imported it into xtensa for building and running the model.
However, while building i encountered an error:

#### Assertion failure at line 4373 of /build/tree/RG-2017.7_kuma/p4root/Xtensa/Software/xcc/be/cg/whirl2ops.cxx:

#### Compiler Error in file U:/workspace/CNN/tensorflow/lite/core/api/flatbuffer_conversions.cc during Code_Expansion phase:

#### XGOTO block doesn't have goto's? (1315943)

xt-xcc ERROR:  C:/usr/xtensa/XtDevTools/install/tools/RG-2017.7-win32/XtensaTools/libexec/xcc/be.exe returned non-zero status 3

I am not able to figure out the cause for this error.Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the command you're using to try to build for XTensa? It's unclear from the question if you're using the https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/micro build process or something else.

Comment: Hello!Thanks for the reply.  I used -clang -std=c++11(Language dialect)for the compiler to build this c++11 project.The project's makefile was run in Linux environment and it working in linux based system.But when i try to use it in Xtensa(Windows environment) i am facing this error.Is it something to do with makefile?Could you please let me know where i went wrong?